# What mongodb command I should run to know server info?

Tags: mongodb

For example, I want to know the database directory that is used by mongodb to run what it is?

The documentation said that the default data is in /data/db however, there is no such directory

I wonder if there is a mongodb command to get that simple info. I look through the web and could not find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the [Configuration Parameters](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters) used with:

```
> db.serverCmdLineOpts()
```

For example:

```
{
    "argv" : [
        "mongod",
        "--dbpath",
        "/usr/local/db"
    ],
    "parsed" : {
        "dbpath" : "/usr/local/db"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Any parameters not specifically listed will be using their default values.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a folder called data anywhere in your system.
Then let Mongo know where the this folder is by updating the path.

in windows you would run this on the command line.

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath c:\test\mongodb\data
```

This is where your mongo stores your data.

Comment: That's not really what the OP was asking.